# Themes for the Microsoft Expression series of programs?

Tags: themes, microsoft-expression

[Microsoft's Expression Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Studio) Blend, Web, Design, etc. all have two themes -- Light and Dark.

Is it possible to obtain and use other themes?

Answer (score 3):

There's a whole bunch of themes on the official [Microsoft Expression Theme Gallery](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=themes). Take your pick.

**EDIT : My original answer is non-applicable - question asked was not themes for documents, but rather themes to change the look and feel of the app itself. Updated answer below.**

Microsoft Expression uses a mix of native Windows UI elements, and also Windows Presentation Foundation elements. As such, it is really tough to edit even the base colors alone, so unfortunately, the answer is...

**Nope, you can't haz more.**

Comment: Sorry, had to vote you down on that one.  These are themes for APPLICATIONS you create using Expression.  These are not themes for the Expression applications themselves.

Comment: No worries on the downvote, i'm not going to hunt you down at your address and stick a knife in you. :) Sorry for misreading your question, I get what you mean now - Look and Feel of the app itself.

Comment: Can you source me on your update?  I'll mark as answer (sometime)...